# Let A be a nonempty subset of R. Define -A = {-a: a ∈ A} and prove bounding relations between A and -A

Tags: real-analysis

```
a) Prove that if A is bounded below, then -A is bounded above.
```

By the completeness axiom, A has an infimum, inf(A).

Drawing out a sample number line it is easy to visualize that the infimum (glb) is the suprema of -A. What tools can I use to prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**: Use: $x \ge M \implies -x \le -M$. Its simple .